# Not finding PushContext class under omnifaces-2.2.jar

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I am building a project in Eclipse to run the the Omnifaces showcase to study how the library works, but the `PusbBean.java` is not being found.

The class `org.omnifaces.cdi.push.PushContext` is not in the library **omnifaces-2.2.jar**.

There is any new version available? Did I miss something?

Comment: See also http://omnifaces.org#snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version is **omnifaces2.3-SNAPSHOT** here is the dependecy information

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

and this jar contain `PushContext` interface

**Note:-** This is Snapshot and not the final release as i saw @BalusC discussing about this Push component with core JSF development team.

[image: > Blockquote]

Now check **omnifaces2.0 javadocs**

[image]

It clearly showing no such package exist in **version2.2**

Comment: That is right.. I miss the package still under development.

Thanks guys!